# Change laravel welcome file name

Tags: php, laravel, render

I changed the files path after i installed laravel framework like this:

from:
resources/views/welcome.bandle.php

to
resources/views/admin/index.php

and the routes file to:

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin/index');
});
```

the url is working
but all the larvael render not working
like this:

[image]

what i need to do?

tnx a lot.

Comment: Try changing the filename to `index.blade.php` otherwise it won't be treated as a blade template, just a plain PHP file.

Comment: @JeffLambert are you sure just checked the source it replaces '/' with '.' using https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/View/ViewName.php#L13-L24 I think it's some other problem

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA Fairly confident, it would explain why the `@` directives are showing instead of being evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the .blade.php extension to the files you want to parse using "Blade Engine", that will remove all the tags you have within curly braces.

Next, you need to write your route like this:

```
Route::get('/admin', function(){
    return view('admin.index');
})->name('admin.index')->middleware('auth');
```

It is a good convention naming the routes for easy access across the application, that way you can simply reference it in the blade views like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.index') }}">Admin page</a>
```

That way you will have the dynamic route no matter from where in the file structure you call it.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also use your `Controller` to display such view. By this you'll write your routes more cleaner. Let's say we have an `AdminController` that handles all admin processes and functions. Put your `dashboard.blade.php` inside `views/admin` directory.

The route:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
```

The controller:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
     public function index()
     {
         return view('admin.dashboard'); // in views->admin->dashboard.blade.php
         //add some data here
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep 'blade' in view file name if you don't plan to use controller, e.g.:

```
resources/views/admin/index.blade.php
```